# What IAM role is required to see bytes billed on a Bigquery table with row level security?

Tags: google-bigquery

Having trouble trying to figure out what IAM permission/role is required that isn't Owner/Editor to see bytes billed on tables with row level security. Does anyone know what it is exactly? [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-row-level-security#limit-side-channel-attacks) says `BigQuery Stackdriver Metrics Monitoring Viewer roles` but it seems like Monitoring Viewer is not enough and I can't seem to find what IAM roles `BigQuery Stackdriver Metrics` is referring to.

Comment: Hi @pliftadc94, Does these 2 [Link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/row-level-security-intro#:~:text=An%20authorized%20user%2C%20with%20the,policies%20on%20a%20BigQuery%20table.) and [Link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-row-level-security) will help you ?

Comment: @ArpitaShrivastava no

Comment: Can you check this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control) for access to Cloud Monitoring ?

Comment: That does not help either.

Comment: Can you check this [Link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/What-is-the-required-permissions-role-to-see-bytes-billed-on-row/m-p/667196/highlight/true). I hope it will help you for IAM permission/role ?

Comment: That was my own question, which sadly didn't help either.